# How do I get Tome of Polymorph: Turtle since Cataclysm?

Tags: world-of-warcraft

Turning an enemy into a turtle is an important ability every mage should know. I am playing with a new mage who will soon be needing this critical skill. Unfortunately, I don't have the tome to teach it handy.

Before Cataclysm, the tome dropped in the Zul'Gurub, but this raid was removed by the shattering. Happily, there is a [blue post](http://forums.worldofwarcraft.com/thread.html?topicId=27291810112&sid=1) (ie from a Blizzard employee) confirming that the tome will still be available somehow. But the post is not even slightly specific about how the tome will be available.

So...

**How do I get a Tome of Polymorph: Turtle since Cataclysm?**

(I'm watching the auction house in case someone puts up one that dropped from the old source, however that may be gold prohibitive, and will quickly become unreasonable to find. I want to know what the new source is.)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As of Cataclysm, you can now acquire *Tome of Polymorph: Turtle* [by fishing](http://www.wowhead.com/item=22739/tome-of-polymorph-turtle#comments:80). It's a random reward from any school of fish in the new level 80+ Cataclysm zones (Mount Hyjal, Deepholm, Twilight Highlands, and Uldum).

Comment: Any fishing spot?  All the commentors in that thread have fished it up from fish pools in the new Cataclysm zones.

Answer (score 2):

As of today? You buy it on the auction house.

As of today, "Other Means" has not been elaborated upon.

Looking forward, I'd keep an eye on [The Amazing Zanzo](http://www.wowhead.com/npc=32712) in Dalaran. With the removal of the old Polymorph Pig quest in Azshara, he now teaches that spell, and I wouldn't be surprised to see Turtle added to him, if it's not added as a rare drop from some zone or boss.

Comment: You're right, today I probably won't get a useful answer. I keep forgetting that Cataclysm itself isn't actually out yet, because the world has changed, and I'm playing with low level characters.